# aws-php-sdk dynaomodb client creation issue

Tags: laravel, aws-php-sdk

I have installed aws-php-sdk in Laravel and configured it correctly where putitem / getitem working when executing through HTTP/HTTPS in the browser and curl. However, when I try to execute the same script through Laravel queue, I am getting this exceptions when trying to instantiate aws client:

local.ERROR: App\Jobs\processjob::failed(): Argument #1 ($exception) must be of type App\Jobs\Throwable, Error given, called in /var/www/html/myappname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php on line 260 {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): App\Jobs\processjob::failed(): Argument #1 ($exception) must be of type App\Jobs\Throwable, Error given, called in /var/www/html/myappname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php on line 260 at /var/www/html/myappname/app/Jobs/processjob.php:46)

I am using AWS role permission to access dynamodb. I have tried to debug for hours with no luck. Please help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is very simple, `processjob` class has a `failed` method (overriden), and it is asking for `Throwable $exception`, your issue is that `Throwable` was not imported like a global class (`\Throwable`) so the PHP thinks it is a class local to the current namespace (`App/Jobs`).

So, your code should be like this:

```php
function failed(\Throwable $exception)
```

or, another solution is:

On top of the file (after the `namespace` keyword), write this: `use \Throwable;`.

If this does not fix your problem, let me know and share your `processjob` class, but this should do it...

Comment: Adding the failed method helped but now getting a different error:

/var/www/html/myapp/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php(159): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\TaskQueue->run()

Like before, going through the browser works but through the processjob fails with the above error.